# Clarify vs. Better Clarify

Tags: modifiers

Can something be "better clarified?"

I discussed the phrase with a coworker, and I believe the word "clarify" does not need a modifier. In essence, when you say clarify, you are implying that you have better clarified.

Comment: [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clarify) gives one sense for 'clarify' :<< _v.tr.
1[a]. To make ... easier to understand_ >> and 'easier' accepts an intensifier here (much).

Answer (score 1):

The question involves a confusion between the act of clarifying and the thing being clarified.

It is generally true that clarifying X makes X better. In other words, the X itself is usually better after the clarification than before. The clarification, as distinct from the X that is being clarified, however, cannot be said to be either better or worse, unless there is some other clarification that we are comparing it to.

So for the locution *better clarified* to make sense, there needs to be a context that involves two (actual or possible) acts of clarification. For example, suppose that something that was unclear has been clarified to some extent: it is now clearer, but still not very clear. One can then meaningfully ask for it to be 'better clarified', that is to be made still more clear.

Answer (score -1):

We can ask for a 'detailed clarification' on something, or used as "Can this be clarified in detail?". But 'better clarified' / 'more clarification' is not a good usage.

Comment: This sounds more like a personal opinion than an answer. Let me offer a sincere countervailing opinion: I think "better clarified" is perfectly fine and sensible. There, now there are two opinions for the OP and future readers to pick from. So how do they pick? Can you please extend your answer with rationale, ideally from authoritative sources, to move us out of the realm of pontification and into credibility?